# Why is the counter not being reset to 0 in a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm watching the MIT intro to ComScip and have to do a recursive call. I had trouble fitting in a counter nicely to count the number of string appearance. With a stroke of luck and playing with the position of the counter, the follow solution works but I don't WHY:

```
import string
target = "banana"
key = "an"
key_len = len(key)
found_pos = 0
found_pos = string.find(target,key)

def countSubStringMatchRecursive (target, key):
    counter=0
    found_pos = string.find(target,key)
    if(found_pos!=-1):      
        print "found"
        slice_pos = found_pos + key_len
        counter = countSubStringMatchRecursive (target[slice_pos:], key)
        counter+=1
        #print counter
    return counter

print countSubStringMatchRecursive (target, key)
```

Here is my understanding:

First recursion:

1. initialize counter=0
2. if key is found is target, counter=countSubStringMatchRecursive (target[slice_pos:], key)
   This should reset the counter to 0 again because the main function is being ran
3. counter+=1
4. return 1 as the counter value because 0+1=1

The part I don't understand is why counter=0 not re-initializing the counter to 0. Instead, it lets itself to accumulate the previous value and produce the right result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counter` is a variable local to the method. This means that each recursive stack frame (each new method call gets a new "stack frame") has its own copy of `counter`. Therefore, while `counter` is set to `0` every time the method is called, all these copies of `counter` are in fact DIFFERENT pieces of memory, and do not affect one another.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Few questions: 1. How do we know which counter copy is being returned since there are multiple copies? Is it always the initial copy being returned (the first stack)?

Comment: Yes, when the method returns `counter`, it returns it's OWN copy of `counter`. Thus, when you call it the first time, you'll get back the first copy of `counter`. Basically, you can think of it as if your method is a black box and you don't care what it does internally. So when you call it recursively, just assume that it'll give you back the right answer and not mess with any of your variables.